# Difference between FILE_URI and NATIVE_URI in cordova plugin camera

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

What is the different between FILE_URI and NATIVE_URI in cordova plugin camera?

Answer (score 5):

There are three options, and from what I understand they are different per platform:

```
Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
    'file://' ios
    'content://' android

Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI
    'assets-library://' ios
    'content://' android

Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
    'data:image/jpg;base64,'
```

If you want to convert them to other urls you can use the file plugin: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function (path) {
    window.alert('getPicture.success: ' + JSON.stringify(path));
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(path, function (fileEntry) {
        window.alert("success: " + JSON.stringify(fileEntry));
    }, function (e) {
        window.alert("error: " + JSON.stringify(e));
    });
}, function (e) {
    window.alert('getPicture.error: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
}, $scope.options);
```

Here is the documentation for the options:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera/blob/master/www/CameraConstants.js

And also the link to the source code for this function:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/www/resolveLocalFileSystemURI.js

Comment: Any idea how to choose between the gallery and the camera in the cordova-camera

Comment: Yep! In your options object you can pass through: {sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA} or {sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType. PHOTOLIBRARY}

Comment: I am sure you don't mean to say sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA|| Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY :D, If you know what I mean! I mean to say it should give a pop up asking to select either one, now we need to create that pop up by ourselves and write duplicate code .. Argh!

Comment: Yeah, you need to create your own pop-up in html with two buttons, clicking the gallery you pass through Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY and for camera use Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA. I'm working on a plugin which allows you to select Gallery from the video camera view, but it's not finished! https://github.com/kmturley/cordova-plugin-media-custom